# CPU usage by SQL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

Is there a way to determine the CPU usage by SQL in MySQL? There doesn't seem to be any obvious ways to do that using sys and performance_schema.

Answer (score 0):

If on Linux, you can see the CPU usage of the `mysql` process by using the `top`
command.

You may also use the script of
[MySQLTuner](http://blog.mysqltuner.com/download/):

[image]

If you are experiencing slow queries, ensure that slow query logging is on
(it is off by default in most distributions)
and look at the log to see what queries are your culprits.

For more information see the article
[Identifying MySQL Slow Queries](http://www.ducea.com/2006/11/06/identifying-mysql-slow-queries/).

Comment: Thanks harrymc, using top and vmstat was the first thing I did when troubleshooting an issue recently, mysqld was using 100% CPU(1 core as vmstat showed really less overall CPU usage) and was the top process. Using "show processlist" I was able to find threads of one user running many  SQL without indexes. A restart of the instance solved the issue(But with no obvious conclusion about which SQL had the most impact). Slow query log did not seem to capture these SQL probably because they were still running. Still being able to tell what SQL and its thread was using all the CPU it would help.

Comment: Restarting the instance stopped these queries, so problem "solved". If you can identify these queries, then try to optimize them, maybe by adding indexes. If not, turn on slow query logging and hope for them to finish.